# Inconsistent delete query with left join of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables in MySQL v5.6 created by:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tm (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE th (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE tr (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    tm_id INT,
    th_id INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (tm_id) REFERENCES tm (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (th_id) REFERENCES th (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO tm (id) VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO tm (id) VALUES (102);
INSERT INTO th (id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO tr (tm_id, th_id) VALUES (101,1), (102,1);
```

So in the end I have three tables with following data:

```sql
th

| id |
|----|
|  1 |


tr

| id  | tm_id   | th_id |
|-----|---------|-------|
|  11 |     101 |     1 |
|  12 |     102 |     1 |


tm 

| id   |
|------|
|  101 |
|  102 |
```

And what I am trying to do is to delete all of them with one SQL query:

```sql
DELETE th, tr, tm
FROM th
LEFT JOIN tr ON tr.th_id = th.id
LEFT JOIN tm ON tr.tm_id = tm.id
WHERE th.id = 1;
```

As a result `th` and `tr` tables will be blank but tm will be left with id=102

```sql
+------+
|   id |
+------+
|  102 |
+------+
```

And I am not searching for better query but trying to understand why tm.id=101 was deleted but tm.id=102 was left in the table?

Comment: A LEFT JOIN on a DELETE is a decidedly odd thing

Comment: I agree, but just trying to understand behaviour of MySQL in this case.

Comment: This deletion, taking into account foreign keys, is ambiguous. *As a result th and tr tables will be blank but tm will be left with id=102* I cannot reproduce this. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6fd1ccf9ae7d47d3a34f830d69e6f16d), [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9AaceZhtrLkZ6UoDB6jcP8/0) - all available MySQL/MariaDB versions were checked.

Comment: @Akina Hm, very weird will check.

Comment: @Akina In your test fiddle, you selected from th twice, but not from tm, tm shows the remaining entry. @ bgr11n: it's probably a bug, related to your foreign keys (something similar to e.g. [this bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44207))

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of the `InnoDB` storage engine which is used (as default) to create the tables and the foreign key constraints.

Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=28506c6658677112787b4392632975a9) without foreign keys and the result is that all rows of all tables are deleted.

You would get the same result, even with the foreign key constraints if you created the tables with the `MyISAM` storage engine.
Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=792c3d1b5f7722706cfe631e47be2538).

But for the `InnoDB` storage engine and the foreign key constraints, as it is mentioned in [13.2.2 DELETE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html):

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables
> for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might
> process tables in an order that differs from that of their
> parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls
> back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the
> ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables
> to be modified accordingly.

so what you get may be the result of a rollback for the deletion of `id = 102` of `tm`, because the order of the tables processed is such that it would violate a foreign key constraint.
Check the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=358b2fd5f0939101d33b4d5cecac2c6f).